# JQuery toggle not collapsing properly in IE6

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle

I've got 3 divs using JQuery's toggle function to collapse divs:

[image]

The divs collapse fine in Firefox, but in IE6 (target browser), this happens:

[image]

If I resize the IE window, the divs go back to looking normal, as they do in Firefox.

I've tried to get the code down to its simplest form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<title>BIIS Portal</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="cache" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../assets/stylesheets/core-css.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/core-js.js"></script>
<!-- This script doesn't seem to work when put it in its own .js file... why? -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide (collapse) the toggle containers on load
    $(".toggle-container").hide(); 

    //Show all containers with class toggle-opened
    //Remove the opened class
    //Find the trigger for the now opened container and apply the active class
    $(".toggle-opened").show().removeClass("toggle-opened").prev(".toggle-trigger").addClass("active");

    //Switch the Open and Close state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
    $(".toggle-trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <div>
                <div class="portlet">
                    <div class="portlet-header">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                        <h2>BI - External data Control</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="toggle-trigger">External Data Configuration</h3>
                            <div class="toggle-container toggle-opened">
                                blah
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="toggle-trigger">Current Notifications</h3>
                            <div class="toggle-container toggle-opened">
                                blah
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="toggle-trigger">General Information</h3>
                            <div class="toggle-container toggle-opened">
                                blah
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

core-css.css:

```
@import "base.css";
@import "framework.css";
@import "elastic.css";
@import "superfish.css";

@import "/application/css/jquery.autocomplete.css";
@import "/application/css/hspi-content-nav.css";
@import "/application/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css";
```

core-js.js is merely several JQuery libraries minified, namely:

- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.2
- jQuery Cycle Plugin (with Transition Definitions) Version: 2.86 (05-APR-2010)
- jQuery Cycle Plugin Transition Definitions Version:   2.72
- jQuery UI 1.8.12
- jQuery UI Widget 1.8.12
- jQuery UI Mouse 1.8.12

I'm not too sure what's happening, as I've mostly copied existing code. I need to get it working right in IE, so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mitch. I think your main problem it's your CSS styles. You dont provide CSS code, but next example is worked in my tests in IE6-8 and FF7 (except that IE6-7 do not support CSS `content` style) http://jsfiddle.net/2YyXC/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <div class="portlet-header">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                    <h2>BI - External data Control</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="toggle-trigger toggle-trigger-active">External Data Configuration</h3>
                        <div class="toggle-container toggle-container-opened">
                            blah
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="toggle-trigger toggle-trigger-active">Current Notifications</h3>
                        <div class="toggle-container toggle-container-opened">
                            blah
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="toggle-trigger toggle-trigger-active">General Information</h3>
                        <div class="toggle-container toggle-container-opened">
                            blah
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle-trigger-active").next().toggleClass("toggle-container-opened");
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.portlet {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.portlet-body {
     padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.portlet-title {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.toggle-trigger {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.toggle-trigger:before {
    content: "► ";
}

.toggle-trigger-active:before {
    content: "▼ ";
}

.toggle-container {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    display: none;
}

.toggle-container-opened {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew. This seems to work perfectly, except I've obviously lost all the styling. I'll have a play around with it and see if I can get it looking like it's supposed to without turning the toggles dysfunctional. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add conditional comments for ie6 with .toggle-container and/or .toggle-closed (not sure if you're using that class) display:none

Comment: How would I add `display:none` as an IE6-specific CSS property in jQuery? There is no toggle-closed as far as I can see, by the way. I think the removal of the `toggle-opened` class in the jQuery code is an implicit way of saying that it's closed.

Comment: <!--[if IE 6]>
<style>.toggle-container,.toggle-closed{display:none}</style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: Where would that go in the HTML? I'm relatively new to this stuff.

Comment: right after your <link> element, since there is no toggle-closed, use .toggle-container{display:none} .toggle-container.toggle-opened{display:block}

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work - maybe because there doesn't seem to be a `toggle-closed` class.

Comment: right, thats why in the comment above your last one, i corrected it

Comment: Thanks albert, but it's still not working with: `<!--[if IE 6]> <style>.toggle-container{display:none} .toggle-container.toggle-opened{display:block}</style><![endif]-->`

Comment: damn man. sorry i dont have ie6 booted up to look. try this, set position:relative on toggle-trigger and toggle-container and put a z-index on both, making toggle-trigger's z-index higher. like, .toggle-trigger,.toggle-container{position:relative} .toggle-trigger{z-index:100} .toggle-container{z-index:10}  hope that works

Answer (score 0):

A common problem is that things simply aren't redrawn as they should be. If resizing the window or zooming the page work, it's a redraw error and as far as I know there's abolutely nothing you can do about it in code, other than trying to find some other way of coding it that works.